# Getting ClassCastException from MainActivity when using onEditorActionListener

Tags: android

I'm following the example [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html), but I'm getting a ClassCastException on the line that says:

```
EditNameDialogListener activity = (EditNameDialogListener) getActivity();
```

Comment: Have you downloaded and run the project or have you incorporated the code into your own project?

Comment: Yeah, I was incorporating the code into my own project.  I omitted something in my MainActivity's class definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D'oh!  I forgot to add `implements EditNameDialogListener` to the class definition for MainActivity.  That's why the cast didn't work.  (Thanks, folks.)